# Positioning text relative to image position

Tags: css, html

Basically, image is centered(I cant use absolute positioning because everyone has different screen resolutions and the image is centered) and I want my text to be 20 pixels down from top and 10 pixels right from left. How do I do it ? I have searched but got nothing. Probably due to my typing.

Comment: Do you want your text to overlay the image? You want the text to start 20 pixels down from the top of the page? Or from the bottom of the image? And is the 10 pixels from the left side of the page or from the left side of the image?

Comment: Overlay the image. from the top of image. everything is relative to image.(as in 10 pixels left from corner of image)

Comment: Edited my answer due to new info from you. See if it helps.

Comment: Alright, see my answer.

Comment: ty everyone. both perfect solutions, marked pandavengers as answer beign the oldest one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit:

Since you want the text to be overlay you can use a hack using `position: relative` on the wrapping element and `position: absolute` on the inner ones. This allows you to position inside the wrapping element as long as the wrapping element has a `width` and `height`;

http://jsfiddle.net/FcBmd/1/

Irrelavent Text From Previous Answer: *Something maybe using `text-align: center`
http://jsfiddle.net/FcBmd/*

Comment: I dont see how that does help, since text cant overlay image in that case.

Comment: I did not see his comment, but there's this thing called `position: relative` you see =)

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of options. You're going to need to use a div the size of your image and center that. Then you can either set the image as the background of that div, or you can make the div `position: relative` and add an `<img>` tag that is positioned absolutely.

Here's an example of the first approach.

HTML:

```
<div id="imageContainer">
    Some text that's overlaying the image.
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#imageContainer {
    width: 275px;
    height: 95px;
    background: url('https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo4w.png');
    margin: 0 auto;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    padding: 20px 0 0 10px;
}
```

And a JSFiddle to show it working: http://jsfiddle.net/VD34W/

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this: http://css-tricks.com/float-center/.

Basicly it's only possible to align left and right but you can 'somehow' fake it.

Answer (score 0):

you can try using the `padding`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

HTML

```
<div id="theDiv">
    <p>Some text here</p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#theDiv {
    background: url(https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSvT90hfqXnsPUsrySmYtU2Hj1ypEwCq0muzSCKdxOSmUnZqp_Z);
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
}

#theDiv p {
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-left: 10px;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BkKmC/)

Comment: when you center everything, paddings doesnt matter

Comment: yes but I just gave the solution of your problem to move the text down 20px and right 10px!

Answer (score 0):

Good question.

Basically you say how far down from the top and how far left.

```
position:relative;
left:10px;
top:-20
```

Tip: put both the picture and text inside a div so that the text is relative to the div.

Also checkout:  http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp